# Limit RAM usage by gdal_merge

Tags: gdal, gdal-merge, ram

When trying to use [`gdal_merge.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html) (from [`alpine-normal-3.2.1`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/osgeo/gdal/alpine-normal-3.2.1/images/sha256-c4292a09110a050e8c5428b51db33172ace077ea357b39a3bbb2513054d23562?context=explore)) to actually merge 4 large raster files (roughly 6 GB each) this way:

```
gdal_merge.py -o merged.tif -of GTiff input_*.tif
```

my computer memory went through hell:

[image: memory overflow]
*Synthetic figure drawn by hand to catch the idea, but not actually representing the true behaviour...as it freezed the computer.*

RAM (magenta) is 12 GB, swap (green) is 5 GB.

Is there a way to limit RAM usage by `gdal_merge` in order to avoid a crash?

The current results are not encouraging, because the command abruptly ends with:

```
0Killed
```

Comment: Create a tiled TIFF for making it possible to flush smaller chunks of data into disk `-co TILED=YES`. Also converting the source images into tiled ones, if they are not, will help with reading data as smaller chunks. Check the block size withgdalinfo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`gdalbuildvrt`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html) to merge to a virtual raster (a small xml/text file) then [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html) to the final tif:

```
gdalbuildvrt merged.vrt input_*.tif
gdal_translate merged.vrt merged.tif
```

Suggest you look at the `-co` options in `gdal_translate` to add compression.

Comment: Furthermore, [`GDAL_CACHEMAX`](https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html) will affect memory usage/how often `gdal_translate` flushes to disk.

Comment: Increasing cachemax may have negative effect https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalWarp.